# Nokia HERE control for C#.Net (REST)

Tags: c#, rest, maps, here-api

I'm looking for a map control which is written in C# to use Nokias HERE REST-Api. Is there anything hat can handle it or do I have to build it from scratch? Unfortunately I can't find any. I just found the Windows Phone SDK (https://developer.here.com/native-apis/windows-phone-sdk), but I need Windows Forms (or WPF).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Map Tile API](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile) combined with a map control. From my experience in map applications, I would recommend this one for WPF/Silverlight/WinRT: https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/